# In Python, how do I define an arbitrary number of indexed variables in a function?

Tags: python, function, numpy

First off, thank you in advance for bearing with my novice understanding of Python. I am coming from MATLAB so hopefully that gives some context.

In MATLAB I define a mathematical function as:

```
f =@ (x) 2*x(1)^2 + 4*x(2)^3
```

In Python, I wrote:

```
def f(x):
   return 2*x(1)**2 + 4*x(2)**3
```

But I get an error inside my other function (finite difference method for creating gradient vector):

```
line 9, in f
    return 2*x(1)**2 + 4*x(2)**3
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

(an input X1 that contains n-number of entries, specified by the number of variables in the original equation, is fed back into the function f(x) to evaluate at a specific point).

**Update 2021-10-22**
Below I have included the code for reference. **THIS CODE CURRENTLY WORKS.**

The main thing I am wondering is how I can create *an arbitrary number of variables for an equation like I do in MATLAB with x(1),x(2)...x(n)*. I have been told I should use `def f(*x)` but when I add the '*' operator on f(x) I get a `tuple index out of range` error.

```
import math, numpy as np

def gradFD(var_init,fun,hx):
    df = np.zeros((len(var_init),1)) #create column vector for gradient output


    # Loops each dimension of the objective function
    for i in range(0,len(var_init)):
        x1 = np.zeros(len(var_init)) #initialize x1 vector
        x2 = np.zeros(len(var_init))
        x1[i] = var_init[i] - hx
        x2[i] = var_init[i] + hx

        z1 = fun(x1)
        z2 = fun(x2)

        # Calculate Slope
        df[[i],[0]] = (z2 - z1)/(2*hx)
        


    # Outputs:
    c = df #gradient column vector

    return c
```

**And the test script:**

```
import math
import numpy as np
from gradFD import gradFD

def f(x):
    return 2*x[0]**2 + 4*x[1]**3 #THIS IS THE NOW WORKING CODE
    #return 2*x**2 + 4*y**3
var_init = [1,1] #point to evaluate equation at

c = gradFD(var_init,f,1e-3)
print(c)
```

Comment: For those of us who don't know MATLAB, what does `x(1)` do? Similarly, in the MATLAB example, what is `x`? I assume you have a 2xN matrix in numpy and you want to use columns 0 and 1, right?

Comment: `x(1)` in Matlab is the same as `x[0]` in Python.

Comment: @tdelaney x(1) x(2)...x(n) references a variable in the function. You can think of x(2) as 'y'. It's just a way to create a function with arbitrary variable names as iterations of 'x' instead of having to specify x,y,z, etc in all interfacing functions (like the finite difference function that is using this equation)

Comment: Its a good question. SO seems to be down vote happy these days. What's missing is a __simple__ example of the python code which would let us know this is numpy and we'd see what columns were there. You want to post a simplified example that can be used to test the answers. The tags aren't quite right, I'll make an edit on those.

Comment: Another reason for a working example. Tim Robert's answer assumes you are passing in a single parameter that is a numpy array of at least 2 columns. You could also pass in an arbitrary number of variables just by changing it to `def f(*x)`. Now `x[0]` and `x[1]` are two different variables instead of 2 columns of one array. You could pass in two numpy arrays of multiple dimensions and do the calculation across both of them.

Comment: Okay I see. I am going to update my original post with the code (it's not that long) and hopefully that helps.

I like what you are saying about the f(*x) because I think that is what I am going for. However that throws an error in my code, saying 'tuple index out of range' when it is running the finite-difference gradient function on that equation.

Comment: @tdelaney I added the (now working) code. However, when I try the 'def f(*x)' instead of 'def f(x)' I get a 'tuple index out of range' error.

The code works as-is now that I got the advice to use [] instead of (). What exactly does f(*x) do that f(x) does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indexing in Python is done with square brackets, not parentheses.  And remember that Python starts in indices at 0, not 1.

```
def f(x):
    return  2*x[0]**2 + 4*x[1]**3
```

Comment: may I add to your solution the comment that he can create a lambda function (with I think is analogous to Matlab anonymous functions) ?

f = lambda x: 2*x[0]**2 +4*x[1]**3

Comment: Naming an anonymous function defeats the purpose...

Comment: @UlisesBussi - that's not a good idea. A lambda is anonymous... so why assign it to `f`, thereby unanonymizing it? If you want a function to have a name, use `def` as shown here.

Comment: @UlisesBussi, he CAN do that, and that's the normal way in several other languages (Javascript, for one), but that's not the Pythonic way.  He should write Pyhon like Python, not like Matlab.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I suppose I never thought about the fact that you are calling a specific index position of a variables vector (or 'array' I suppose?)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called `f` but you are trying to call `x(2)`. You get the error because you are trying to call `x` as a function, but `x` is a numpy array